# How do I programmatically set a flag's custom entity reference field when programmatically setting the flag?

Tags: hooks, flags

Some background: I'm new to Drupal 8/9 module building. I need a particular content type's nodes to be automatically flagged.
I have this working using the code below.
However, the flag involved also has a custom field I need to set.

- It's an entity reference field (to another node)
- I want to set the flag's custom entity reference field to be the same value as an
  entity reference field on the flagged node.

(This may seem like a strange thing to do. There may be a better way to accomplish the UX goals. I still want to know how to do it.)

'rf_tweaks' is the module machine name, 'research_note' is the node content type, and 'research_item' is the name of the flag.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

function rf_tweaks_node_insert(Node $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'research_note'){
 $flag = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('flag')->load('research_item');
 \Drupal::service('flag')->flag($flag, $node);
}
}
```

There's some great info at the [flag api page,](https://www.drupal.org/node/1748148) but the methods are different enough that it's not clear to me how to adapt them to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in your last line of code returns the "flagging" entity, which represents the entity/flag relationship. That's the thing you need to set the field on. e.g.

```
$flag = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('flag')->load('research_item');
$flagging = \Drupal::service('flag')->flag($flag, $node);

$flagging->field_foo->target_id = $node->field_bar->target_id;
$flagging->save();
```

That does involve the flagging entity being saved twice, so if performance ever becomes an issue you might need to create a `Flagging` entity manually and save it to avoid the double-hit.

Comment: Working for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: I added commented code to try to understand what's happening... for my own education mostly.
Two questions:
1. Do I have it about right?
2. We use ->save() to add the field value, rather than using the flag service because using the service would crate another flagging instead of altering the current one?